# Trying to create functions with simple equations inside

Tags: c++, function, math

I am new to C++ coding and am doing an assignment for school but I am stuck and can't seem to figure out what I have been doing wrong. The assignment asks that we use functions to carry out some equations involving a 'right-circular cylinder'. Now, I am able to make a code that does what its supposed to do but it doesn't use functions necessarily to calculate the answers. My current code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    double  r = 0,
            h = 0,
            TSurfaceArea = 0,
            LSurfaceArea = 0,
            Volume = 0;

    const double    PI = 3.cylinder   
    cout << "Welcome to the right-circular clyinder area and volume calculator, this program will calculate three things: "
        "\nThe first, is the Total Surface Area."
        "\nThen we will see the Lateral Surface Area."
        "\nAnd Finally we will see the volume." << endl;

    cout << "\nPlease enter a value for the radius: ";
    cin >> r;

    cout << "\nThank you! \n\nNow please enter a value for the height: ";
    cin >> h;

    TSurfaceArea = 2 * PI*r*(r + h);
    LSurfaceArea = 2 * PI*r*h;
    Volume = PI * r*h;

    cout << "Thank you for your input! \n\nSo here are your results based on a radius of " << r << " and a height of " << h << ":" << endl;
    cout << "\nTotal Surface Area is " << TSurfaceArea << "\nLateral Surface Area is " << LSurfaceArea << "\nVolume is " << Volume << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

So like I mentioned, this works but the values have to be assigned as '0' at first and then the equations have to calculate the solutions way down in the code until after a user inputs numbers for 'r' and 'h'. I am sure there's a better way to do this and then I was looking at how to make the equations into functions I can just call later on without having to put a full-on equation everytime I want to calculate with new values which is what the instructor is looking for but I must be doing something wrong creating functions because I can't seem to find a method that works. I have tried this to no avail:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    const double    PI = 3.14159;

    double  r = 0,
            h = 0,

            TSurfaceArea() {
                double tsa = 2 * PI*r*(r + h);
                return tsa;
            }, 
            LSurfaceArea() {
                double lsa = 2 * PI*r*h;
                return lsa;
            },
                Volume() {
                double v = PI * r*h;
                return v;
            };

    cout << "Welcome to the right-circular clyinder area and volume calculator, this program will calculate three things: "
        "\nThe first, is the Total Surface Area."
        "\nThen we will see the Lateral Surface Area."
        "\nAnd Finally we will see the volume." << endl;

    cout << "\nPlease enter a value for the radius: ";
    cin >> r;

    cout << "\nThank you! \n\nNow please enter a value for the height: ";
    cin >> h;

    cout << "Thank you for your input! \n\nSo here are your results based on a radius of " << r << " and a height of " << h << ":" << endl;
    cout << "\nTotal Surface Area is " << TSurfaceArea << "\nLateral Surface Area is " << LSurfaceArea << "\nVolume is " << Volume << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Now I know this should be relatively easy to resolve but I feel like I'm just missing something and hopefully someone can help me out! Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not how you define functions. Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: That's not how you define a function.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no objects here that I can see.  You're using C++ as "a better C".

It's been a long time since I've written C or C++, but I think you want something more like this.  I've taken the meat out of the main to emphasize my point:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

static const double    PI = 3.14159;  // surely you can do better than six digits

double topSurfaceArea(double r, double h) { return 2.0*PI*r*(r+h); } 
double lateralSurfaceArea(double r, double h) { return 2.0*PI*r*h; }
double volume(double r, double h) { return PI*r*r*h; }  // your formula was clearly wrong.

int main() { // removed body for simplicity }
```

Comment: Don't forget you have to declare the functions before `main` to use them in `main`

Comment: Thanks for that, I had made it more complex than it really was, missed some simple things. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, NathanOliver - I've fixed the sample.

Answer (score 0):

A lambda is maybe the closest to what you want,eg for a rectangle

```
double width,height;
auto area = [&](){ return width*height; };
width = 5;
height = 10;
std::cout << area();
```

would print `50`. However, you probably better learn about functions first...

```
double area(double width,double height) {
    return width * height;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << area(5.0,10.0);
}
```

Note that the function declares a return type (`double`), it takes some parameters (`double` and `double`), and it has neither a `,` nor a `;` after its definition.

Comment: @Jarod42 not the first time i make this stupid mistake. thanks